# Convert mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm;ss AM/PM to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

When I am trying to convert date I am getting below error

```
DECLARE @MinLogDate AS varchar(100)
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME

SET @MinLogDate = '10/26/2012 01:23:90 AM'
SET @MinDate = (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, @MinLogDate,103),101))
```

Error:

> *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

How can I convert the varchar time to datetime?

**EDIT**

based on the answer i have modified.. below is the actual date time i am getting .. so now I am able to get mindate but max date is not working

```
    DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @MaxDate AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @MinLogDate AS varchar(100)
    DECLARE @MaxLogDate AS varchar(100)

    SET @MinLogDate = '8/1/2012 01:00:00 AM'
    SET @MaxLogDate = '8/31/2012 01:00:00 PM'

    SET @MinDate = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@MinLogDate, 10), 101)
    SET @MaxDate = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@MaxLogDate, 10), 101)

    SELECT @MinDate
    SELECT @MaxDate
```

Comment: `CAST('10/26/2012 01:23:59 AM' as datetime)` should work, it does not in your case as `01:23:90` is not a valid time (90 seconds?) Is your question *how to deal with invalid dates*? If so what parts can be invalid?

Comment: @AlexK it is not 90, for dummy purpose I have inserted similar date but made a mistake.

Comment: So you just want the date part? Is you date order mdy? Try 
`set dateformat mdy; select CAST('10/26/2012 01:23:59 AM' as date)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: **CHANGE:** As above answers I changed Date Format type 101 from 103.

```
DECLARE @MinLogDate AS varchar(100)
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME

SET @MinLogDate = '10/26/2012 01:23:10 AM'
SET @MinDate = (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Cast(@MinLogDate AS DATETIME), 101), '-', '/')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `103` is British/French `dd/mm/yyyy` and you appear to be converting from U.S. `mm/dd/yyyy` which should be `101`.

Judging by the `CHAR(10)` in your code - are you just looking for the date part? If so then this should be adequate:

```
SET @MinDate = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@MinLogDate, 10), 101)
```

**UPDATE:**

Further to your updated question, this should now do the trick:

```
SET @MinDate = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@MinLogDate, CHARINDEX(' ', @MinLogDate)), 101)
SET @MaxDate = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@MaxLogDate, CHARINDEX(' ', @MaxLogDate)), 101)
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine in query window but when I am doing the same in SP I am getting this The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data
 type resulted in an out-of-range value.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "
ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: I have edied my answer based on your solution

Answer (score 1):

Time and date covered.

Break them down into constituent elements.

```
DECLARE @MinLogDate AS varchar(100)
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME
SET @MinLogDate = '10/26/2012 01:23:30 AM'


DECLARE @minLD varchar(16) 
DECLARE @minLT varchar(16) 

-- In response to user's comment
SET @minLD = LEFT(@MinLogDate,CHARINDEX(' ',@MinLogDate));
SET @minLT = RIGHT( @MinLogDate, LEN(@MinLogDate) - CHARINDEX(' ', @MinLogDate));

SELECT @MinDate = CONVERT(datetime, @minLD, 101) + CONVERT(time, @minLT)
```

**NOTE:**

I changed your time string to be a valid one before proceeding :)

**Extra note**

Like Barry, I changed `103` to `101`.

EDIT: in response to ever changing question :D

Comment: +1 but these are not working for the max datetime. Can you please consider the edit part once again

Comment: Your @MaxLogDate is not set to anything.

Comment: I checked that when the date is in two digit then it is working fine like '8/10/2012 01:00:00 AM'
or '8/01/2012 01:00:00 AM'

Comment: ok, give that a go.  Instead of going for a hard character limit, I'm using charindex to split.

Answer (score 0):

below are all the formats I have used in the past:

```
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 101)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1) 
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 10) 
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) 
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)
    select CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate()+0.20, 121)
    select CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate()+0.20, 21)
    select CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate()+0.20, 20)
    select CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate()+0.20, 120)
    select convert(varchar (10),CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate(), 120),110)

    select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)), 0), getdate() - 1) + 1 ----- this shows the week of month - which week today's date is in the current month

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)-- format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + SUBSTRING( convert(varchar, getdate(),108),1,5)-- format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm

    select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) + stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),GETDATE(),109 ),15 ),7,7,' ')-- format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) +' '+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 9), 13, 5) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9), 25, 2)-- format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM



    select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) + right(convert(varchar(32),GETDATE(),100),8)
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100), 7)
    select convert(varchar,getDate(),120)
    select convert(varchar(10),getDate(),120)



    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy 
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd 
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) -- dd mon yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) -- mon dd, yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) -- hh:mm:ss
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) -- mm-dd-yyyy
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) -- yyyy/mm/dd
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) -- yyyymmdd
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) -- dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 114) -- hh:mm:ss:mmm(24h)
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
    SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
```

Comment: You should add more to this showing how it answers the question. Posting code is not an answer. Explaining how it works is an answer.